# method or field in scala inheritance

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
class Data(i: Int)

class Person(@transient val data: Data) extends java.io.Serializable

class Student(data: Data) extends Person(data)
```

I thought data is a field of Student class, but actually, it is a method of Student,

```
classOf[Student].getMethods.foreach(m => println(m.getName()),
```

The above code prints `data`

I would ask `why data becomes method of Student, but not field,`

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala classes all public fields are actually private fields accessed via public methods.

This can be demonstrated using just your `Data` class, examining its status after phase 4 ("typer") of compilation.

```sh
%%> cat so.sc
class Data(i: Int)

%%> scalac -Xprint:4 so.sc
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // so.sc
package <empty> {
  class Data extends scala.AnyRef {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val i: Int = _;
    def <init>(i: Int): Data = {
      Data.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `val i` is `private[this]` and if you run `classOf[Data].getFields.isEmpty` it will return `true`.

Now let's add a public field or two to it.

```sh
%%> cat so.sc
class Data(val i: Int) {
  val x = 'X'
}

%%> scalac -Xprint:4 so.sc
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // so.sc
package <empty> {
  class Data extends scala.AnyRef {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val i: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def i: Int = Data.this.i;
    def <init>(i: Int): Data = {
      Data.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val x: Char = 'X';
    <stable> <accessor> def x: Char = Data.this.x
  }
}
```

We see that both `val`s, `i` and `x`, are `private[this]`, and `classOf[Data].getFields.isEmpty` will still return `true`, but now there are also methods, `def i` and `def x`, that are public and return the expected values of `Data.this.i` and `Data.this.x` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

`Person` has public getter method called `data`.

```
scala> :javap -public Person
Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Person implements java.io.Serializable {
  public $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Data data();
  public $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Person($line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Data);
}
```

Because `Student` is a child of `Person` it inherits this method.

`Student` has `data` too, but without `var` or `val` it's just a local variable, which is visible only in the body of `Student`, so it's not a member.

You can read more at [Tour of Scala: Classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html)

Comment: Thanks @duelist for the great anwser!